# Como carregar um script em JS quando a página não está em cache?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, microsoft-edge

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma extensão (só para mim por enquanto) para o Microsoft Edge Chromium que muda a fonte do GitHub, mas ela não muda quando eu reseto o cache da página, aqui vai o script que eu fiz (é somente ele e nada mais), ele funciona perfeitamente, o único porém é que não executa as vezes:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    let blob_num = document.getElementsByClassName('blob-num');
    for (let i = 0; i < blob_num.length; ++i)
        blob_num.item(i).style.fontFamily = "Cascadia Mono";
        
    let blob_code_inner = document.getElementsByClassName("blob-code-inner");
    for (let i = 0; i < blob_code_inner.length; ++i)
    {
        let blob_code_inner_style = blob_code_inner.item(i).style;
        
        blob_code_inner_style.fontFamily = "Cascadia Mono";
        blob_code_inner_style.fontSize = "11px";
    }
}
```

Para quem não entendeu, é o seguinte, eu entro num arquivo qualquer no GitHub, e o script executa normalmente, mas se eu apertar `Ctrl` + `R` para resetar o cache e recarregar a página, ou entrar em alguma página em que eu nunca entrei antes no GitHub, o script não é executado, eu já tentei algumas coisas além da propriedade `window.onload`, como por exemplo o `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoad", ...);` e algumas outras que não me recordo no momento, mas que também não funcionaram :/

Como faço pra isso funcionar? Não sou mt bom em JS, mas espero ter sido claro o suficiente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está tentando executar esse script?

Você está abrindo as ferramentas de desenvolvedor e rodando ele?

Se for dessa forma, o script não vai persistir mesmo, não tem o que ser feito.

---

Agora correndo o risco de estar tentando solucionar um problema que não é o seu caso, se você quer ter um script de usuário persistente rodando em determinado site, o que você precisa é de um gerenciador de scripts como Greasemonkey ou Tampermonkey.

Nele você pode declarar um código JavaScript para rodar em determinada página toda vez que ela é carregada através das meta informações do script, por exemplo:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GitHub Font
// @version      1.0
// @description  Troca a fonte do Github para Cascadia Mono
// @author       Luiz Fernando
// @match        https://github.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==
```

Com essas meta informações você teria um script rodando toda vez que você acessar uma página com a URL `https://github.com/*`. No caso o asterisco é um curinga, o que significa que a qualquer página que começar com `https://github.com/` será válida para esse script.

Você pode ser mais específico utilizando `https://github.com/github/*` por exemplo.

---

Agora quanto ao script para trocar a fonte, talvez também seria melhor adotar outra abordagem, pois se você for fazer um select de elementos na página para mudar o estilo deles via JavaScript, você só irá conseguir alterar os elementos que já estão carregados no momento que você rodou o código.

Para alterar o estilo de todos os elementos, que já estão carregados, e que ainda irão carregar, seria mais prático anexar um `style` na página declarando o estilo desses elementos. Algo do tipo

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GitHub Font
// @version      1.0
// @description  Troca a fonte do Github para Cascadia Mono
// @author       Luiz Fernando
// @match        https://github.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerText += '.blob-num { font-family: "Cascadia Mono" !important; }';
    style.innerText += '.blob-code-inner { font-family: "Cascadia Mono" !important; font-size: 11px !important; }';
    document.head.append(style);
})();
```

E esse seria um exemplo de user script para alterar a fonte da página.

Comment: Eu estou rodando ele em uma extensão que eu criei para o Edge, é bem simples, e irei dar uma olhada nesses gerenciadores de script que vc falou, obg

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu fiz isso e deu mt certo :)